# find name of least experienced employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello friends I am stuck in writing one query.
Can you please help me out?
I have one table called `prog` and having column `doj`.
Here in `name` column I have name of all employee and in `doj` column I have their date of joining.
I have to find out the name of least experienced employee so I write this query to find the least experienced employee using their date of joining:

```
SELECT 
min(DATEDIFF(YEAR,doj,GETDATE()) - 
(CASE WHEN 
 DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YEAR,doj,GETDATE()),doj) > GETDATE()
 THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'least experience'
FROM programmer
```

I am not able to find out the `name` of employee.
If I use the column `name` with `group by` the I get list of all employee with their name and year of experience.
How can I find out the name of only that particular employee having least experience.
Thanks in advance and waiting for reply.

Comment: do you have one primary key in this table?
I suggest Employee_id you can have as primary key on this table.

Comment: @pratikgarg no i don't have any primary key on this table & i don't have the employee_id column....there are many other columns but i need only those two column for my query that's why i have not post the other columns

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table .....*

Comment: well . @CeejeeB has given the perfect answer for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will select the programmer with the most recent start date.

```
Select top 1 name, doj 
from programmer
order by doj desc
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....this gives me the desired output...i am thinking how can i forget the top function....but any way thanks for your help.....